# What is different Job as a argument at CoroutineScope and launch?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

This two code run exactly same. What is different putting Job in CoroutineScope and launch?

```
private val job = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main).launch(start = CoroutineStart.LAZY) {
    for(i in 10 downTo 0) {
        Log.d("test", ": $i")
        delay(1000)
    }
}

CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main+job).launch{ }

CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main).launch(job) { }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Technically, both result in the same behavior, but the main point is that neither is a good way to use the `CoroutineScope()` factory. This is the idiomatic way to write the same thing:

```
GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main+job) { ... }
```

If this raises your eyebrows ("*Don't use GlobalScope!*"), that's because it should — your examples are just another way to make the same mistake, with more verbose code. You construct a `CoroutineScope` without holding a reference to it, resulting in exactly the same unbounded and non-cancellable scope as the `GlobalScope` singleton.

In addition, the way you use a `Job` instance that is a handle to an actual coroutine, is also wrong: the job associated with a coroutine scope should be a standalone instance returned from either `Job()` or `SupervisorJob()`. Its only purpose is to serve as the central point from which to cancel the entire scope or inspect its state.

Comment: Thank you for your advice!  If you don't mind, can you give me an example code of way use Job? Like returned from Job() or SupervisorJob().

Comment: Something like `val rootScope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main + Job())`, which is equivalent to the shorter `CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main)` because it will add a `Job()` if missing. Then, when you want to cancel the work, use `rootScope.coroutineContext.job.cancel()`

Comment: Correction to the above comment: just `rootScope.cancel()` is enough, it's an extension function that does the same.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't seem like there are many differences between the two, looking at the source code. The `operator fun plus` [documentation states](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.coroutines/-coroutine-context/plus.html)

> Returns a context containing elements from this context and elements
> from other context. The elements from this context with the same key
> as in the other one are dropped.

which explains how your first test works. For the second, calling `launch` with a context parameter, calls into [`CoroutineScope.newCoroutineContext`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/new-coroutine-context.html)

> Creates a context for the new coroutine. It installs
> Dispatchers.Default when no other dispatcher or
> ContinuationInterceptor is specified, and adds optional support for
> debugging facilities (when turned on).

and looking at the source code of it:

```kotlin
public actual fun CoroutineScope.newCoroutineContext(context: CoroutineContext): CoroutineContext {
    val combined = coroutineContext + context
    val debug = if (DEBUG) combined + CoroutineId(COROUTINE_ID.incrementAndGet()) else combined
    return if (combined !== Dispatchers.Default && combined[ContinuationInterceptor] == null)
        debug + Dispatchers.Default else debug
}
```

We can see it also ends up using the `operator fun plus`.

There are some other differences that seem negligable to mention here, but ultimately the context of the launched coroutine looks to be the same in both of your tests.